# Reload table automatically from mysql with angular

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm calling an information from my mysql database with http.get(url) in angular and finally populate a table with that information.

This is working but now I want that the controller calls the http.get(url) when there is a change in the database automatically without refreshing the page manually.

Comments or tips are well received :D 
(I'm kind of new with angular).

this is my currently code:

data.js

```
angular.module('demo', [])
.controller('Hello', function($scope, $http, $timeout) {

$scope.loadData = function(){

$http.get('http://localhost:8888/nuevo/respuesta.php').
    then(function(response) {
        $scope.greeting = response.data;
        //console.log($scope.greeting);
        //console.log("hola");
    });

};//se cierra la funcion

$scope.loadData();
});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="Hello">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Banda</th>
                <th>Cancion</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in greeting">
                <td>{{x.`enter code here`IdCancion}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Bandas_Musicales}}</td>
                <td>{{x.Canciones}}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <button ng-click="loadData()">reload</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Show some code.. It increases your chances of getting help.

Comment: oh sorry, here you go.

Answer (score 0):

In order to notify you client of data changes on the server you need to find a way for the server to contact the client. A popular solution for this is websockets, maybe look into that. Also, some php frameworks have something in place for this already.
If you don't want to get into websockets you could think about refreshing the table data every x seconds in order to keep it up to date.

Comment: thank you for your answer? i will look about websockets :)